# Maple 2017- question: boundary value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, maple

I am having some trouble to solve boundary value problem on maple 2017, I suspect there is some thing wrong with the way I am using boundary conditions.

NOTE: I suppose you have to have maple in order to help. Please do not be annoyed.

This the ODE:

$          eq1 := diff(z0(x), x, x) = -z0(x)+cos(2*x)      $

This is command to solve it with boundary conditions:

$  sl1 := dsolve({eq1, z0(-\frac{\pi}{4}) = 0, z0(\frac{\pi}{4}) = 0})  $

This is the output:

$ sl1 := z0(x) = \frac{(cos(x)*cos((\frac{\pi}{2})}{3*cos (\frac{\pi}{4})}-(1/3)*cos(2*x)      $

First term on RHS(the fraction) should be zero.
Can some one help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have likely used the lowercase name `pi` instead of capitalized `Pi`.

That lowercase name has no special meaning for Maple. You want `Pi` instead.

Comment: Yes that was the problem. Thank you!